# Is there a way to automate printing for HP large format printers?

Tags: printing, scripting

first post here.

Trying to figure out a way to write some sort of program, probably a bat script for now, to be able to automatically print a specific document on our HP z6 large format printer. The software for it is called "HP Click" and upon a quick google search I can't seem to find any way to control it through basic scripting.

Would I be able to just use the normal printer function built in to windows?

My ideal script would essentially do the following:

*Start*
Prompt user to enter a unique code '(product#)'
navigate to a network location and import (product#).pdf into HP click
Print on the large format printer
Navigate to another folder
find a different document (product#)_label.pdf
If the label is 4x1, print 5 copies to label printer "4x1"
If the label is 4x2, print 3 copies to label printer "4x2"
*End*

I'm sure I could figure out the labels, whether I'd be able to pull the document size via the pdf or if I'd need to reference a database is a different question.

Is this possible? Or because it's a large format printer would I be better off continuing to have employees manually input the document into HP click and print the labels via the GUIs? I ran into a problem this morning with someone importing the wrong files into HP Click and wasting half a roll of material trying to get a file to transform via a print software. Yes we have guides, no they didn't read them.

I've yet to try implementing this as I don't really know where to start or if it's possible. Any advice would be appreciated!

Thanks!